# how to perform slide bar navigation so that UITabBar also moves

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have taken a empty application,initially login screen is shown.On entering valid credentials user is navigated to home page where TabBar is shown.On tapping settings icon tab bar should move half way aside.But with my code settings screen is underneath tab bar.How to do so that TabBar also moves.I dont want to use any 3rd part controls.Looking for help.Thanks in advance.Below is my code:

```
-(void)login{
UIViewController *viewController1 = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController * firstNavigation = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController1];

UIViewController *viewController2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController * secondNavigation = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController2];

tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tabBarController.viewControllers = @[firstNavigation ,secondNavigation ];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:tabBarController animated:NO];


}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
_isSideMenuOpen = NO;


UIButton *imageButton1a = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
imageButton1a.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,30,30);
[imageButton1a setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"setting_icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[imageButton1a addTarget:self action:@selector(goToSettings) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *barItem1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:imageButton1a];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barItem1;

lbl=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 100, 150, 30)];
[self.view addSubview:lbl];
lbl.text=@"test label to move";

myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor brownColor];
[myView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 60, -160, 480)];
[self.view addSubview:myView];

}
-(void)goToSettings
{

if (_isSideMenuOpen)
{
    _isSideMenuOpen = NO;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [myView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 60, -160, 480)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
  //  self.view.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,320,self.view.frame.size.height);

}
else
{
    _isSideMenuOpen = YES;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [myView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 60, 160, 480)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
   // self.view.frame=CGRectMake(160,0,320,self.view.frame.size.height);

}

}
below is screen shot of o/p I got
but expected o/p is UITabBar should move
```

[image: thats the output i got with my code]

Comment: Replace `[self.view addSubview:myView];` with `self.tabBarController.view addSubiew:myView];`